# VS 2008 Team ASP Drop down change not rendering after save

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, rendering

I am attempting to make changes to a ASP drop down list, when they are save whether i debug, build, save, save all. The changes do not render. The list items are the same. Please assist, Why do the changes not relect in the solution.

```
 <tr>
 <td><asp:Label ID="Lblsection" runat="server" Text="Section:"></asp:Label></td>
 <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dpsection" runat="server" Height="54px" Width="199px">
     <asp:ListItem>Dependency Section</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Service Record Books Section</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Customer Service Support Section</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"        
     Text="Please select a section" ControlToValidate="dpsection" 
     InitialValue="***SELECT ONE***"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
```

Comment: is it happening to all the control or just this DD List?

Comment: just this DD list, i made a DD change to a different database, Saved and it was instant, my end user checked and was content. As of late, i've known of this page and the DD, but its at a point where it has to be fixed. Makes no sense. Three options now "service rec book/Cust Serv Support/**Select One** <---which is not listed as a list item, it was in the old list......

Comment: I made the last change to a ASP Drop down maybe 4 months ago, it was instant. Is there anybody that has exprienced this? Visual Studio team system 2008, win server 2003. Changes to code, adding buttons. changing rules works fine, asp brop down list items do not render....please help thanks